# How do I use Google's Vision API to convert a PDF (non-searchable) to a searchable PDF?

Tags: pdf, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision

From what I've seen, Google's Vision API lets you perform OCR on a PDF, but it returns *only the detected text* in a JSON format. What I need is a searchable (OCR'd) PDF file in return. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the [OutputConfig type](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.OutputConfig) doesn't have any metadata field to configure the resulting file's format. As you are already aware, the API returns a JSON response. You could either first get the JSON data with the API and explore the use of any of the following [repositories for JSON to PDF conversion](https://github.com/topics/json-to-pdf) or directly use any specialized module such as [OCRmyPDF](https://pypi.org/project/ocrmypdf/#description) that specifically serves this purpose on your source PDF and avoid the use of the API altogether.

Comment: There is even [a fork of OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/ualiawan/OCRmyPDF/) which calls the Google Vision API instead of using Tesseract as the official version does.